# Nesper engine always tries to load types from Nesper.dll first

Tags: esper, nesper

Every time I try to add a new type to my `nesper` engine, I get the following exception thrown in the nesper engine.

```
Could not load type 'K2Common.Order' from assembly 'NEsper, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

The engine eats the exception and then finds the proper type in my assembly as it iterates over each loaded assembly.

Is there a way to prevent nesper from searchign for a type in the nesper.dll first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I resolved the problem by using the Qualified assembly name

```
configuration.AddEventType("OrderEvent", typeof(Order).AssemblyQualifiedName);
```

instead of the below:

```
configuration.AddEventType("OrderEvent", typeof(Order).FullName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Among the configuration settings, there is a "import" list that you could try to clear out.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define the SearchPath (assemblies in this case) that NEsper will use to find its assemblies.  Though in practice, the best answer is to use the AssemblyQualifiedName.  Using the typed functions i.e. AddEventType() will automatically use the AssemblyQualifiedName.